# Where can I find the version of Laravel-boilerplate I am using?

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-8, boilerplate

I am currently adding features to a Laravel website that uses boilerplate as its CMS. I'm having trouble finding which boilerplate version is being used and there is no one at work who knows. Composer.json also does not contain the package and it's version (because it's a direct clone of the GitHub repo).

[This is the boilerplate package that I'm using](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look inside the cloned directory. Usually, when you clone a repo, the .git folder is inside the cloned repo (if no one deleted it). That could give you a clue about what time it was cloned by running `git log -1`.